# The strange case of Japanese Websites

Tags: website-design, user-experience, japanese, usability

Japanese Websites are strange entities that live a digital world far away from the one we are used to. They probably have their standards, that are still obscure to me - and it's not a matter of language.

The Japanese Web Designers seem to be stuck in a space-time continuum where the good of the user is not contemplated: they produces websites full of images that in most of the cases include buttons and large blocks of text. This structure can lead to a potentially huge usability issue and critically increase the page loading time. It is only an example, but it is emblematic.

I really don't understand Japanese Web Design. So please, help me to understand it.

Comment: Could you give us some specific examples of such sites?

Comment: Hi Gabriele, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. I agree with JTL here: please add some examples of your issues with these sites, with screenshots. That might make answering your question a lot easier. Thanks! You can use the [edit] button (or this one) to ad info to your question. If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to go there (20). Keep contributing and enjoy your time here!

Comment: This article posits some theories: http://randomwire.com/why-japanese-web-design-is-so-different/

Comment: Nice article @DA01. Gabriele, I am curious about this too, but I think you got a down-vote because your question is missing.... well, an actual question :) "Why is Japanese design so strange?" could be it. What in particular caught your eye?

Comment: It's an interesting subject, I agree the question needs more specifics though, and I'm not sure anyone could do much better than that article. Very interesting read!

Comment: I think this is a really interesting question, and would like some japanese webdesigners have a look at it. Anyone know anyone? :)

Comment: Older Reddit discussion with more than 200 comments: [Modern Japanese Websites Still Look Like 90s Geocities Homepages: Example 1 (Why is this?!)](https://www.reddit.com/r/japan/comments/14kuzc/modern_japanese_websites_still_look_like_90s/)

Comment: Thanks for the replies and for the handy article! :) 
@Yisela it's more like an open request than a simple question. I would to discuss upon the topic.

Comment: I have no examples to show you at the moment, because this situation is related to the most part of the japanese websites. Just google it and try for yourself. 
I will try to find some good and rappresentative examples btw.

Comment: I think it has to do with the difference in writing system and the fact that japanese like to read.